# Is Django has something like "database middleware"?

Tags: python, django, database, middleware, django-middleware

Django has middleware to achieve do somthing when request and response. Is Django has "database middleware" to achieve do somthing when write data and read data.

For example,some old database does not support to utf8mb4 , so it can't support all of emoji. If Django has "database middleware" I will encode data when it is being saved , And decode when it is being reading.

Comment: I don't answer your question, but perhaps I can help you with another approach. There is a new feature in the upcoming django [utf8mb4 encoding with MySQL 5.5](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18392). Meanwhile the people there are discussing an alternative solution for the moment. :)

Comment: You should check out [django signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/).  You can call functions pre and post save from any database model, essentially being a middleware.

Comment: If you really want to go deeper into implementing this solution, perhaps you could dig into the source code how they implement the [DB backend](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/db/backends)

Comment: Perhaps this might help if you are already good in Django. [James Bennett Django in Depth](https://youtu.be/tkwZ1jG3XgA?t=4m38s). Brace yourself it is 3hours but you just need to watch the next 1 hour for your problem.

Comment: @Yeo Thank you very much~ It is a pity I think I'm not good in Django . Maybe I will read it  in the near future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [overwrite model methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) specially save method to achieve this.

Example from docs
from django.db import models

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tagline = models.TextField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # your intended modification
        do_something()
        super(Blog, self).save(*args, **kwargs) # Call the "real" save() method.
        do_something_else()
```

Also check [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#pre-save) and [post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#post-save) Model signals.

Comment: does not cover the `decode` part when it was being `read` from the database.

Comment: @Yeo Django Model Descriptors is a good candidate to solve this. [Good explanation here](http://blog.kevinastone.com/django-model-descriptors.html)